# Stack around the variable 'returnedstring' was corrupted

Tags: c, memory

I am trying to write a function that will return the largest ASCII letter from each word.

So my string is { "hello", "and", "good", "morniny" };
My return value should be "onoy".

I am struggling with it and keep getting an error that my variable "returnedstring" is corrupted:

> Stack around the variable 'returnedstring' was corrupted.

I get this error on the last row of my "MaxLetterToNewString" function.
I tried many workarounds, even freeing this variable.
Why do I get this error?

And what should I do to fix it?

Originally I use the function to return the value, but since
it didn't work, I thought to get the value in a
new variable I called "jr" (JustReturn).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char MaxLetterToNewString(char *str[], int size, char *jr);

void main()
{
    char* blabla = " ";
    char* arr[] = { "hello", "and", "good", "morniny" };
    //char newarr[] = { NULL };
    char newarr;
    int size = 0;
    size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char*);
    //*newarr = (char*)malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char));
    newarr = MaxLetterToNewString(arr, size, *blabla);
    if (*arr == '\0')
        printf("Memory not allocated");
    else
        puts(*arr);
    free(*arr);
}

char MaxLetterToNewString(char *str[], int size,char *jr)
{
    int wordsize, letterstillnow = 0;
    char returnedstring[] = {NULL};
    char resultarr = '\0';
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        wordsize = strlen(str[k]);
        for (int i = 0, j = i + 1; j < wordsize; i++, j++)
        {
            if (str[k][i] >= str[k][j])
                resultarr = str[k][i];
            else
                resultarr = str[k][j];
        }
        returnedstring[k] = resultarr;
        returnedstring[k + 1] = '\0';
    }
    jr = returnedstring;
}
```

Comment: `char returnedstring[]={NULL};` isn't going to allocate enough memory, neither can it be used by the function's caller (if that's the intention). The function itself does not return a value, please check out the compiler warnings.

Comment: Eventually `free(*arr);` in `main` isn't going to do you any favors either.

Answer (score 0):

An observation about how arrays are stored in memory (elements of arrays are stored sequentially) and what a character array is, i.e., a sequence of null terminated characters provide intuition to the following solution:

Consider an array of words as a sequence of characters with `'\0'` as a separator between the words. Scan the sequence while checking for the end of the current word, i.e. `'\0'` character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *MaxLetterToNewString(char **str, int size) {
    char *result = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*result));

    int nullCounter = 0, max = 0, i = 0;
    char c;

    while (nullCounter < size) {
        c = *(*(str + nullCounter) + i++);
        if (c == '\0') { // we reached the end of the word
            i = 0;
            ++nullCounter;
            result[nullCounter - 1] = max;
            max = 0;
        } else if (c > max)
            max = c;
    }

    result[nullCounter] = '\0';
    return result;
}

void main() {
    char* arr[] = {"hello", "and", "good", "morniny"};

    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char*);
    char *result;
    result = MaxLetterToNewString(arr, size);
    printf("%s\n", result);

    free(result);
}
```

Comment: @WhozCraig Since I don't change the `str` pointer anywhere, thus it always points to the beginning of the array and `i` represents an offset from the beginning. I've tested it couple times and it works just fine. Sure, I might be missing something but as it is right now I don't see a problem here.

Comment: `i` represents an offset from `*str`, which is the *first* string in the sequence of pointers. There is absolutely no guarantee the string literals participating in that array of pointers are contiguous in memory. That's the problem i refer to. If the code above works, its by luck, not defined behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for the clarification. I've based my solution on the wrong assumption that not only pointers but also the data they refer to are stored in contiguous chunk of memory. Updated my code to reflect this.